# Bootstrap on Chrome Not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-lg-4 col-sm-push-4" style="background-color: blue">
            Content C
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-lg-4 col-sm-push-4" style="background-color: pink">
            Content D
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-pull-8" style="background-color: purple" >
            Content A
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-pull-8" style="background-color: purple">
            Content B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

So  I am trying to achieve the following display on chrome.  It works perfectly on safari.

```
Desktop:
[ 1st col ][ 2nd col ][ 3rd col ][ 4th col ]

Mobile:
    [ 3rd col ]
    [ 4th col ]
    [ 1st col ]
    [ 2nd col ]
```

Is my syntax wrong or am I supposed to include some extra steps. I have tried adding col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 to every line but that didn't seem to help or hurt.

So I think the real question is that bootstrap is not rendering for me on chrome. On safari it shows up as [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvckuakg1ajxttu/Screenshot%202015-04-28%2018.23.10.png?dl=0_).  On chrome it shows up as [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixpaqlzoddxmg0x/Screenshot%202015-04-28%2018.21.19.png?dl=0).
Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that because you are not adding the columns up to 12

If you wanted it to look like your diagram you can just put the class

```
<div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-12"></div>
```

will do what you are looking for also you might not even need col-sm-12 bootstrap tends to automarically make each column full width if it is not specified for smaller screen widths

Link to jsfiddle for example http://jsfiddle.net/tw1gqocq/1/

update :::: 
This is to get the correct ordering.
And bootstrap cdn should start with https://

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6" style="background-color: purple" >
            Content 3rd
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-push-6" style="background-color: green">
            Content 4th
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-pull-6" style="background-color: blue">
            Content 1st
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-pull-6" style="background-color: pink">
            Content 2nd
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry I had those lines in there I just didn't copy my code correctly. I have edited my question. Unless you mean something else.  On chrome it just shows as a row for every class instead of splitting it into columns.

Comment: I added a link to a jsfiddle you can check it out and just adjust the screen size to see it work http://jsfiddle.net/tw1gqocq/

Comment: Is the real question how to make the mobile view be seen in a different order?

Comment: Ok it seems bootstrap is just not rendering for me in chrome. This is the code you just posted.  https://s3.amazonaws.com/thisismyamazingawesomewebsite.com/test-website.html does this work for you in chrome?

Comment: Sorry I think my question is why does it show up as [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixpaqlzoddxmg0x/Screenshot%202015-04-28%2018.21.19.png?dl=0) for me on chrome. On safari it shows up as [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvckuakg1ajxttu/Screenshot%202015-04-28%2018.23.10.png?dl=0)

Comment: I updated the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tw1gqocq/1/ it now shows the proper order also check you bootstrap cdn I got an error trying to load your cdn in jsfiddle make sure its at https://

Comment: Awesome! glad we got it figured out!! @masterqp